# Select all Childeren in inkcanvas control

Tags: c#, wpf, select, inkcanvas

how can I select all children beside all strokes " I can select all strokes " and I want to select all children  like textboxes and images I used `Inkcanvas.Select(strokes)` for all strokes how can for children?

Answer (score 0):

you can make it manual by

first :create `List<UIElement> elementsToSelect = new List<UIElement>();`

second :add every child in  it

third : `Inkcanvas.select(elementsToSelect)`

you can see this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972125%28VS.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just add something to the above solution, to add every child into the list, you can use class VisualTreeHelper and function GetChildrenCount and GetChild will be helpful.

From Athena Solution, Software Development in Singapore, http://www.athena-solution.com

Answer (score 0):

```
List<UIElement> list = new List<UIElement>();

            GetAllControl("someCanvas", list);

        private void GetAllControl(Canvas c , List<UIElement> list)
        {
            foreach (Control control in c.Controls)
            {
                list.Add(control);

                if (control.Controls.Count > 0)
                    GetAllControl(control , list);
            }
        }
```